# How to test a web application for 100 users and measure the memory usage

Tags: php, laravel, memory, web

I am building a Laravel CMS web application, and am wishing to know the memory usage per user, and simulate up to 250 users and measure the associated memory usage.

I have looked at web-stress tools, but they do not offer a memory usage output (that I can see).

Is there a way to measure the memory usage of a Laravel web application, and is there a way to simulate multiple users drawing on resources at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Apache you can use the [ApacheBench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/programs/ab.html), have a tutorial [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm).

If you use NGIX you can use the Siege like this [tutorial](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/11/benchmarking-and-load-testing-with-siege).

When you test your application you can see memory usage in you SO, in Linux you can use the HTOP for example.